# All links opening in a new tab

Tags: views

I have just inherited a Drupal 8 codebase from someone, and upon getting it all set, I noticed that there is an `open-link` icon against every link (see screenshot), and every link is opening in a new tab. Is this a `settings` type behaviour?

I am three hours old to Drupal (come from React background).
[image]

Comment: This depends on a lot of things, as this could be the doing of a module or some JavaScript. Can you give us the modules enabled on this site, and maybe the HTML of this portion of the page. I know the [`extlink`](https://www.drupal.org/project/extlink) module appends those icons, but never on the local task links of an entity. I'd say an over-eager JS or someone overrode the "link" theme (template), but you'll have to do the hunting.

Comment: Yup ... seems like it is the extlink module. How do I disable it now

Comment: You need to go to your.site.com/admin/modules/uninstall, find the extlink module in the list, select it and press uninstall button at the bottom of the page

Comment: You do not need to disable it. There should be a config page somewhere in the Configuration section to tweak its behavior. If there's a toggle to disable applying it to all links, then turn it off. If it's just the module going wild, you may disable it as a quick fix. Manage modules in the Extend section.